# Cursor returning no data inside a loop, but the data is definitely there

Tags: sql, cursor, procedure

i have a very strange issue going on with nested cursor loops.
i've pasted the code below.  The overall function of the code is to fetch each row from cursor cur1 and use some info from cur1 to run a loop on another cursor cur2.  fairly straight forward - just like a nested 2-tier for loop.  The issue I run into is that when the first (any?) iteration through cur2 produces NOTFOUND, the subsequent/other iterations also produce NOTFOUND even though i explicitly run the cursor select statement manually and see data.  I've also modified the data so that the first iteration DOES have data as a test, and everything works fine...

```
create or replace PROCEDURE       EvalEqu
(prim_indg_ref_in NUMBER,
 stock_ref_in NUMBER)

IS

SD_REF STOCK_DETAILS.STOCK_DETAIL_REF%TYPE; -- Variable used to hold stock_details_ref Stock_details
CAL_REF CALCULATIONS.CALC_REF%TYPE; -- Variable used to hold calc_ref value
CALCSTRG CALCULATIONS.CALCULATION_STATEMENT%TYPE; -- Variable used to hold calculation string from Calculations
CALCSTRGTEMP CALCULATIONS.CALCULATION_STATEMENT%TYPE; -- Variable used to hold calculation as parm values are substitued in
CALCVALTEMP STOCK_DETAILS.DATA%TYPE; -- Variable used hold andcheck calculated value sig figs
CALCVAL STOCK_DETAILS.DATA%TYPE; -- Variable used to populate calc value on Stock_details once calcualted
PARM CALC_COA_VALS.PARM_NAME%TYPE; -- Variable used to hold parm names used for substitution
PARMVAL STOCK_COA_DATA.DATA%TYPE; -- Variable used to hold CoA value from form that replaces PARM value

--Define cursor to hold all calculations associated to a stock record
cursor stock_calc is select SD.STOCK_DETAIL_REF, CALC.CALC_REF, CALC.CALCULATION_STATEMENT
from stock_details sd,
     calculations calc
where SD.LABEL_REF = calc.label_ref
and CALC.Prim_Ing_Ref = prim_indg_ref_in
and SD.STOCK_REF = stock_ref_in;

--Define cursor to hold all parm names and their respective CoA values from form
cursor calc_parms is select CCV.PARM_NAME, SCD.DATA
from calc_coa_vals ccv, stock_coa_data scd
where CCV.COA_VAL_REF=SCD.COA_VAL_REF
and SCD.STOCK_REF=stock_ref_in
and CCV.CALC_REF=CAL_REF;

BEGIN
-- Open calculation cursor
IF NOT stock_calc%ISOPEN then
OPEN stock_calc;
END IF;

-- Loop through each calcualtion for Stock to calculate values
LOOP
FETCH stock_calc INTO SD_REF, CAL_REF, CALCSTRG;
EXIT WHEN stock_calc%NOTFOUND;


-- Open parm cursor to loop through each parm used in calculation
IF NOT calc_parms%ISOPEN then
OPEN calc_parms;
END IF;

FETCH calc_parms  into PARM, PARMVAL;

IF calc_parms%NOTFOUND
THEN
   -- No parameters are associated with this calculation
   --  It is a simple integer and can be returned as such
   CALCVAL := CALCSTRG;

ELSE
WHILE calc_parms%FOUND
LOOP
   CALCSTRGTEMP := REPLACE(CALCSTRG, PARM, PARMVAL);
   CALCSTRG := CALCSTRGTEMP;
   FETCH calc_parms  into PARM, PARMVAL;
END LOOP;

CLOSE calc_parms;

-- evaluate the equation
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT to_char(('||CALCSTRG||'),''999999999990.099999999999999'') from dual ' INTO CALCVALTEMP;


  IF instr(to_char(to_number(CALCVALTEMP)), '.') = 0 -- whole number or 0, no padding
   THEN
     CALCVAL := to_char(to_number(CALCVALTEMP));
  ELSE
    IF ABS(to_number(CALCVALTEMP)) < 1
    THEN
        IF instr(CALCVALTEMP, '-') = 0 -- Indicates positive number
        THEN 
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT LPAD(RPAD(to_CHAR(trunc(to_number('||CALCVALTEMP||'),12-(instr('||CALCVALTEMP||',''.'')-1))), 12,''0''), 13, ''0'') from dual ' INTO CALCVAL;
  
        ELSE -- Negative number
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT LPAD(RPAD(to_CHAR(trunc(ABS(to_number('||CALCVALTEMP||')),12-(instr(ABS(to_number('||CALCVALTEMP||')),''.'')-2))), 12,''0''), 14, ''-0'') from dual ' INTO CALCVAL;

    END IF;
    
    ELSE
        IF instr(CALCVALTEMP, '-') = 0 -- Indicates positive number
        THEN 
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT RPAD(to_CHAR(trunc(to_number('||CALCVALTEMP||'),12-(instr('||CALCVALTEMP||',''.'')-1))), 13,''0'') from dual ' INTO CALCVAL;
  
        ELSE -- Negative number
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT RPAD(to_CHAR(trunc(to_number('||CALCVALTEMP||'),12-(instr('||CALCVALTEMP||',''.'')-2))), 14,''0'') from dual ' INTO CALCVAL;
        END IF; 
    END IF;
  END IF;
END IF;


-- Update stock_details record with newly calculated value
UPDATE stock_details
SET DATA = CALCVAL
WHERE STOCK_DETAIL_REF = SD_REF;

END LOOP;

CLOSE stock_calc;

COMMIT;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);

END;
```

Data for cursor 1: stock_ref=124000

```
STOCK_DETAIL_REF                        STOCK_REF                               LABEL_REF                               DATA                                                         
--------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------ 
217924                                  124000                                  1000                                    1.0                                                                                   
217925                                  124000                                  2602                                    (A1*2)                                                                                
217926                                  124000                                  2603                                    (A1*3)                                                                                
217927                                  124000                                  2604                                    (A1*4)
```

Prim_Ing_Ref = 1234

```
CALC_REF                                Prim_Ing_Ref                  LABEL_REF                               CALCULATION_STATEMENT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
--------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
846                                     1234                                    666                                     1.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
847                                     1234                                    667                                     1.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
848                                     1234                                    690                                     1.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
849                                     1234                                    1000                                    1.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
850                                     1234                                    2602                                    (A1*2)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
851                                     1234                                    2603                                    (A1*3)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
852                                     1234                                    2604                                    (A1*4)
```

Result from cursor1:

```
STOCK_DETAIL_REF                        CALC_REF                                CALCULATION_STATEMENT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
--------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
217924                                  849                                     1.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
217925                                  850                                     (A1*2)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
217926                                  851                                     (A1*3)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
217927                                  852                                     (A1*4)
```

Cursor 2 looks for values for the parameters in the equations and substitutes them for the requested values and evaluates the equations.  Cursor 2 seems to returned nothing for ALL entries in Cursor 1 if ANY NOTFOUND occurs.  so for the 1.0 value, there are no parameters., but this causes the rest of the cursor loops to fail

Cursor 2 data:

```
STOCK_REF                               CALC_REF                                PARM_NAME DATA                                                         
--------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------- ------------------------------------------------------------ 
124000                                  850                                     A1        25                                                           
124000                                  851                                     A1        25                                                           
124000                                  852                                     A1        25
```

these are for the 3 equations shown above in CALCULATION_STATEMENT.  however, as said, the routine fails, just for this specific instance where static numeric values are intermixed with equations (i.e. the cursor2 returns NOTFOUND for at least one item in cursor1).  manually running the cursor's select statement retrieves the data just fine.  I can only assume that the implementation of the cursor is incorrect somehow.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the value of c1 into c2 as a parameter. Have a look at the example here:

[PL/SQL referencing another cursor in a cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982883/pl-sql-referencing-another-cursor-in-a-cursor)

BTW, I assume this line:

```
FETCH stock_calc INTO ...
```

should be:

```
FETCH cur1 INTO ...
```

### Update Following Comments

(Please tick this if you felt I have helped with the answer)

To re-iterate what was said in the comments:

you need to CLOSE calc_parms within IF calc_parms%NOTFOUND THEN... at the moment you only close it in the ELSE statement.

Also, if performance is an issue, you should look at looping through calc_parms before you loop through stock_calc. As calc_parms is not being changed by anything happening in stock_calc, PARM and PARMVAL have exactly the same values in every loop through stock_calc.

Comment: hi nick, yes you are correct, that should be cur1.

the way the two cursors interact is through this:
`and CCV.CALC_REF=CALCULATION_REF;

BEGIN
IF NOT cur1%ISOPEN then
OPEN cur1;
END IF;

LOOP
FETCH stock_calc INTO SD_REF, CALCULATION_REF, CALCSTRG;`

cursor 1 fetches into a variable that cursor 2 uses.  again, this works fine except with the cursor 2 has a NOTFOUND at all in the process.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Please could you edit the code in your original question so that it will run and provide some sample data (for the tables being queried and to use in the params when calling the proc) and expected results so that we can test it?

Comment: hi nick, i completely updated the original question.  I found nothing sensitive about the information provided.  the routine is copied as it exists in our DB.  I added the data and some more information as well.

Comment: The data in calc_parms is going to be identical each time you loop through stock_calc - so if there are no records in the dataset the first time you call it then there will be no records every time you call it within the scope of that instance of the PROC. 

However, if you are saying that it works for the first loop of stock_calc (has data in calc_parms) but doesn't in subsequent loops then you might need to CLOSE calc_parms within IF calc_parms%NOTFOUND THEN... at the moment you only close it in the ELSE statement.

Comment: Interesting, so if calc_params gets a NOTFOUND, t's possible it's just not being closed and reopened...I'll have a look, thanks!

Comment: Superb!  Thanks a lot nick, that was it.  We moved the CLOSE cur2 statement outside the IF and it worked great.  For future reference, to anyone reading this, If your cursor isn't returning data in a loop, make sure it gets CLOSED on all code paths.